# What titles are involved with Avengers Vs X-men?

Tags: comics, marvel, x-men, avengers, avengers-vs-x-men

The Wikipedia page on the Avengers Vs X-men it lists:

### [Titles involved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_vs._X-Men#Titles_involved) [with Avengers Vs X-men]

*This literature-related list is incomplete; you can help by expanding it.*

#### Prologue

- Marvel Point One (one-shot)
- Avengers: X-Sanction #1-4[14]
- Avengers vs. X-Men #0[15]

#### Core miniseries

- Avengers vs. X-Men #1-12[4]

### Tie-ins

- AVX: VS #1-6
- Avengers #25-30
- Uncanny X-Men #11-
- New Avengers #24-
- Wolverine and the X-Men #9-
- Secret Avengers #26-
- X-Men: Legacy #266-
- Avengers Academy #29-

However I was wondering if this was a complete list? Are there other tie-ins and other involved titles?

Comment: @Casebash I don't think so, why?

Comment: Sorry, got confused. I thought this question was talking about the competition

Comment: Oh, no. This is pre-competition. You still need to tag with either [tag:avengers] or [tag:x-men].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Preliminary Reading [The Warm-Up]**

- 00 Marvel Point One #1
- 01 Avengers X-Sanction #1
- 02 Avengers X-Sanction #2
- 03 Avengers X-Sanction #3
- 04 Avengers X-Sanction #4
- 05 Avengers #24.1

**Rounds 0-2: The Reappearance of the Phoenix**

- 06 Avengers vs. X-Men #0
- 07 Avengers vs. X-Men #1
- 08 Wolverine and the X-Men #9
- 09 New Avengers #24
- 10 Avengers vs. X-Men #2
- 11 Avengers #25
- 12 AvX: Versus #1 (Iron Man vs. Magneto; The Thing vs. Namor)
- 13 Uncanny X-Men #11

**Round 3: The Separation of Powers & Prisoners of War**

- 14 Avengers vs. X-Men #3
- 15 Avengers Academy # 29
- 16 Avengers Academy #30
- 17 Avengers Academy #31
- 18 Wolverine and the X-Men #10
- 19 X-Men Legacy #266
- 20 X-Men Legacy #267

[image]

**Interlude: The Phoenix in Deep Space**

- 21 Secret Avengers #26
- 22 Secret Avengers #27
- 23 Secret Avengers #28
- 24 Avengers #26
- 25 Avengers #27

**Round 4: The Search for Hope**

- 26 Avengers vs. X-Men #4
- 27 AvX: Versus #5 (Hawkeye vs Angel; Black Panther vs Storm)
- 28 AvX: Versus #2 (Captain America vs. Gambit; Spider-Man vs. Colossus)
- 29 Uncanny X-Men #12
- 30 Wolverine and the X-Men #11

**Round 5: The Phoenix Five**

- 31 Avengers vs. X-Men #5
- 32 Uncanny X-Men #13
- 33 AvX: Versus #3 (The Thing Vs. Colossus; Black Widow vs. Magik)
- 34 X-Men Legacy #268
- 35 Avengers Academy #32
- 36 Avengers Academy #33
- 37 Uncanny X-Men #14

**Round 6: Pax Utopia**

- 38 Avengers vs. X-Men #6
- 39 New Avengers #25
- 40 New Avengers #26 (The Phoenix Prophecy)
- 41 Avengers #28
- 42 Uncanny X-Men #15
- 43 Uncanny X-Men #16
- 44 Uncanny X-Men #17

[image]

**Round 7: No More Avengers**

- 45 Avengers vs. X-Men #7
- 46 AvX: Versus #4 (Daredevil Vs. Psylocke; Thor Vs. Emma Frost)
- 47 New Avengers #28
- 48 New Avengers #29
- 49 Avengers #29
- 50 Wolverine and the X-Men #12
- 51 Wolverine and the X-Men #13

**Round 8: Wakanda Falls**

- 52 Avengers vs. X-Men #8
- 53 New Avengers #27 (The Phoenix Prophecy)
- 54 X-Men Legacy #269
- 55 X-Men Legacy #270
- 56 Wolverine and the X-Men #14

**Round 9: The Fall of the Phoenix**

- 57 Avengers vs X-Men #9

**Round 10: The Beginning of the Beginning of the End**

- 58 Avengers vs X-Men #10
- 59 Wolverine and the X-Men #15
- 60 Wolverine and the X-Men #16

[image]

**Round 11: The Dark Phoenix Strikes**

- 61 Avengers vs X-Men #11
- 62 Uncanny X-Men #18

**Round 12: Endgame**

- 63 Avengers vs X-Men #12
- 64 Uncanny X-Men #19
- 65 Avengers vs X-Men Versus #6: Hope vs Scarlet Witch
- 66 New Avengers #30
- 67 Avengers #30
- 68 Wolverine and the X-Men #18

**Epilogue**

- 69 Uncanny X-Men #20
- 70 AvX: Consequences #1
- 71 AvX: Consequences #2
- 72 AvX: Consequences #3
- 73 AvX: Consequences #4
- 74 AvX: Consequences #5
- 75 AvX: A-Babies vs X-Babies #1

[image]
Most of this information comes courtesy of [Phil The Comic Guy](http://philthec.blogspot.fr).

Comment: Apparently I posted exactly the same answer as you did... Well at least I quoted my source :p

Comment: Well my source is actually my collection (I'm the sap who owns all of this), but I did reference Phil for the headers, as I remembered liking them, and I used similar numbering. So essentially I agree and have rectified that oversight.  Thank you Kalissar

Comment: Fair enough, I deleted my answer then.

Answer (score 3):

The full list will continue to grow as the end of the series has yet to be solicited, but here is the most recent list, from user jackolover at [CBR](http://forums.comicbookresources.com/showthread.php?402799-AvX-Checklist):

March:

- Prologue - Avengers vs. X-Men #0 -- $3.99

April:

- Avengers vs. X-Men #1 -- $3.99
- Avengers vs. X-Men #2 -- $3.99
- AvX: Versus #1 -- $3.99
- Avengers #25 -- $3.99
- New Avengers #24 -- $3.99
- New Avengers #25 -- $3.99
- Secret Avengers #26 -- $3.99
- Uncanny X-Men #11 -- $3.99
- Wolverine and The X-Men #9 -- $3.99

May:

- Avengers vs. X-Men #3 -- $3.99
- Avengers vs. X-Men #4 -- $3.99
- AvX: Versus #2 -- $3.99
- Avengers Academy #29 -- $2.99
- Secret Avengers #27 -- $3.99
- Uncanny X-Men #12 -- $3.99
- Wolverine and The X-Men #10 -- $3.99
- Wolverine and The X-Men #11 -- $3.99
- X-Men Legacy #266 -- $2.99
- X-Men Legacy #267 -- $2.99

June:

- Avengers vs. X-Men #5 -- $3.99
- Avengers vs. X-Men #6 -- $3.99
- AvX: Versus #3 -- $3.99
- Avengers # 27--$3.99
- New Avengers #27 -- $3.99
- Avengers Academy #31 -- $2.99
- Avengers Academy #32 -- $2.99
- Secret Avengers #28 -- $3.99
- Uncanny X-Men #13 -- $3.99
- Uncanny X-Men #14 -- $3.99
- Wolverine and The X-Men #12 -- $3.99
- X-Men Legacy #268 -- $2.99
- X-Men Legacy #269 -- $2.99

Comment: Matt, is this up today?

Comment: @Pureferret - clearly not. The last issue of Wolverine&X-Men mentioning AvX storyline in earnest was #19 (there were side stories like Utopia kids in his school in later issues but I discount that).

Answer (score 0):

Sources: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers_vs._X-Men#Titles_involved)

---

```
Title           Issue(s)

===========================================
Prologue
-------------------------------------------
Avengers: X-Sanction    #1-4
Marvel Point One        #1
Avengers vs X-Men       #0
===========================================

===========================================
Core miniseries
-------------------------------------------
Avengers vs X-Men       #1-12
===========================================


===========================================
Tie-ins
-------------------------------------------
AVX: VS             #1-6
Avengers vs. X-Men: Infinite #1, #6, #10
Avengers            #25-30
Avengers Academy        #29–33
New Avengers        #24-30
Secret Avengers         #26-28
Uncanny X-Men       #11-19
Wolverine and the X-Men     #9-16, #18
X-Men: Legacy       #266–270
===========================================


===========================================
Epilogue
-------------------------------------------
AVX: Consequences       #1-5
===========================================

===========================================
Other
-------------------------------------------
AVX: Program        #1
A-Babies vs. X-Babies   #1
===========================================
```